# Why is undefined a global property which represents the value undefined?

Tags: javascript

By reading the MDN web doc about `undefined` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), I have read

```
The global undefined property represents the primitive value undefined.
```

Why is it done that way?

`null` is simply a value, why did they create a global property?

Comment: undefined and null are different things, resp. have different meanings. https://www.ajaymatharu.com/javascript-difference-between-undefined-and-null/

Comment: How about this one: http://2ality.com/2013/05/history-undefined.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *why* appears to be lost in time - you will have to ask Brendan Eich about it.

It's just one of [the many quirks surrounding `null` and `undefined`](http://2ality.com/2013/05/history-undefined.html) that `null` is a keyword (literal expression to be precise, that can't be used as an identifier) while `undefined` is not. That's the way it is now, and given that many scripts on the web use `undefined` as a local variable name, it's too late to do anything about it. (At least ES5 made the global `undefined` non-writable).

Answer (score 1):

Their conversion to boolean is the same:

```
!!undefined === !!null
```

however they are there to serve different purposes, undefined itself is a primitive:

```
typeof undefined; //undefined
typeof null: //object
```

Null arose from the need to address the last chain in prototypical inheritance:

```
var obj = new function(){return this};
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))); //constructor's prototype --> Object.prototype --> null
```

Beside many functions inherited from `Node` or `Element` or `HTMLElement` prototype is expected to return an `object`, when they cannot find, they return `null` to hint that they were expected to give you an object, but found nothing instead:

```
document.getElementById("thiswontbethere"); //null
```

Undefined on the other hand is generally preferred for uninitialized values:

```
var obj = {};
obj.someKey //undefined;
Array.apply(null,Array(3)); //[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

And undefined does not have to be global, however if you do:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,"undefined");//{value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

So obviously you cannot change the property descriptor, nor the value itself, but the memory allocation is done on a lower layer, so this is a vendor implementation. It didn't have to be global.

> I somehow feel like this a rant question, and you asked it not for it to be answered but to confirm indirectly that js has some "bad design" elements in it.

Comment: And why does `undefined` have to be a global property…?

Comment: That is a vendor implementation, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,"undefined") does not always have to return something, you can (could) overwrite it, and undefined will still be (would be) in the memory.